# Python - Sending email with attachment using GMAIL smtp gives error

Tags: python-2.7, gmail

I'm trying to send an email using Python and Google's smtp. After calling it I get an error:

```
   msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
TypeError: 'LazyImporter' object is not callable
```

Did anyone had the same problem ? What's the solution for that ?

**My code**:

[Pastebin code](http://pastebin.com/5Zw4UwWk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your imports to

```
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
```